# Is there any way to pass a number stored in a variable to awk for this command?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, awk

I am trying to build a script that takes the days to go back in the log review/analysis as argument:

```
script.sh 5
```

this would show the detailed traffic for the past 5 days on an account. It is based on this command:

```
zcat $path/* |awk -vDate=`date -d'now-5 days' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S` ' { if ($4 > Date) print $1, $12, $15, $16, $17, $23, $24}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -fr | head
```

How can I store that days number as a variable and pass it over to awk?

```
days=$1
zcat $path/* |awk -vDate=`date -d'now-$days days' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S` ' { if ($4 > Date) print $1, $12, $15, $16, $17, $23, $24}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -fr | head
```

Comment: Your `$days` in `-d'now-$days days'` is between single quotes and not evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing a variable to `awk`, you're passing it to `date`

```
awk -v date="$(date -d "now-$days days"  +"[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")" 'script'
```

Comment: I can't even begin to guess at what "a variable within a variable" might mean. The script I posted does exactly what you asked for. Did you try it? If it didn't do what you want then clarify in what way it failed and what you wanted instead. I see your job is technical support so I assume you know how frustrating it is to just hear "it didn't work" with no description of in what way "it didn't work".